# Flutter make container transparent

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, transparency

```
   Material(
      elevation: 30.0,
      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
      child: Container(            
        width: 300,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 30,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'hinttText',
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 2.0,
                ),
              ),
```

),

......................................

......................................

......................................

How do I make my flutter container color to transparent.(only the container. Not Text Field)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Colors.transparent` this sets it to transparent

```dart
Material(
      elevation: 30.0,
      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
      child: Container(            
        width: 300,
        color: Colors.transparent,         //<------ this line
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 30,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'hinttText',
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 2.0,
                ),
              ),
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you , but it's working without elevation(shadow) only :-(.